# Using a specific id, how do you alter href, using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

```
<a id="coverTextURL" href="hero_1_url" target="_blank">
```

When a user clicks a link I would like to change the url of an a href, how do I insert into html?

```
 $('.tab2').live('click', function() {
     $('#TextURL').whatmethod_should_I_use(TextURL)
});
```

Comment: I would rewrite the html. If you use .html(YourNewHtml) you should be fine.
jQuery Html http://api.jquery.com/html/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$('.tab2').live('click', function() {
     $('#TextURL').attr("href", "http://whatever.com");
});
```